# converting a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime data type of the value is out of range

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I get this error because I have datecreated field as smalldatetime as nullable in my DB and EF complains about it. possible solutions are clearly stated on this [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/229/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of)

I would like to follow the 3rd one by setting

`DateCreated = DateTime.Now;`

But if I do that on my Entity class, it will be overritten after next update or recreating of edmx file. 
I would like to achieve it on xaml if possible. I have my

this is how my xaml looks like below, how can I do it? or is there another way.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="DateCreated" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Path= myModel.DateCreated ,Mode=OneWay}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I do that on my Entity class, it will be overritten after next update or recreating of edmx file

That's why Entity Framework generates partial classes. Create a new file with another partial and add the constructor there:

```
public partial class YourEntitiy
{
    public YourEntitiy()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```